# kernel Density simulation on python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to simulate kernel Density on python,

but I get the following error:
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

This is the code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from math import *
from array import *
from import numpy  *
from numpy.random import *
from scipy.misc import *
from scipy.stats import *
from scipy import *
from random import *

N=30
sigma=1
T=linspace(1,N,N)
n=30
X=np.random.normal(0, sigma, 1000)
x=1
alpha=0.45

def k_gaussien(x,sigma): #kernel gaussien
    if(sigma<=0):
        return((1/(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-(x**2/(2*sigma**2))))

def h(n,alpha): #bandwith
    h=ones((1,1))
    for i in range(2,N):
        h[i]= h[i-1] + (i**(-alpha))

def f_PR(x,X,alpha,sigma): #Parzen-Rosenblatt estimator (f_PR)
    global F;
    F = zeros((N,0));
    for k in range(2,N):
        for i in  range(1,k):
            F[k] = F[k-1] + k_gaussien((x-X(i))*(i**alpha));
        F[k] = F[k-1] *(1/(h(n,alpha)));
    print(F);

# almost surely convergency
fPR=f_PR(x,X,alpha,sigma)
plot(T,fPR,lw=3)
plot(T,(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp ((-1/2)*(x*x))*linspace(1,1,N,),'r--')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're quite close. Usually when you get the error that something is not callable, it means that you are using paranthesis, where you should use something else, or you interchanged some variable names.

If you run your code, the backtrace will show you that the error is in the following line:

```
F[k] = F[k-1] + k_gaussien((x-X(i))*(i**alpha));
```

Can you spot the error now? The variable `X` is of type `numpy.ndarray` which is indeed not callable. What you want is `X[i]` probably.

A small stylistic remark: in python you do not need the `;`s.